# dynamically add leading underscore to existing sub

Tags: perl

In this example for perl book, where is "_components" coming from?
I know adding _ to indicate sub is private to the package but this one seems to use leading score out of nowhere. Can you please point me to some source about this? thank you.

```
package Computer;
@ISA = qw(StoreItem);

sub new {
    my $pkg = shift;
    my $obj = $pkg->SUPER::new("Computer", 0,0);
    $obj->{_components} = [];
    $obj->components(@_);
    $obj;
}

sub components {
    my $obj = shift;
    @_ ? push (@{$ojb->{_components}}, @_) : @{$obj->{_components}};
}

sub price {
    my $obj = shift;
    my $price = 0;
    my $component;
    for my $component ($obj->components()) {
        $price += $component->price();
    }
    $price;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_components` is a literal key for the `$obj` hash reference.  It is not "coming from" anywhere.  This is a quirk of Perl syntax. In the statement

```
$obj->{_components} = [];
```

`$obj` is a reference to a newly created instance of a class (in the prior statement) and `_components` is being defined as a key in that instance, and being initialized to a reference to an empty array.  This is equivalent to

```
$obj->{'_components'} = [];
```

For instance

```
$ perl -de0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.55
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> $obj->{a} = "hello";

  DB<2> x $obj
0  HASH(0x800756bf8)
   'a' => 'hello'
  DB<3> p $obj->{'a'}
hello
  DB<4> p $obj->{a}
hello
  DB<5>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `_components` is just a literal key name that the programmer chose. After that, the call to `components` can access the key that was just created.

Part of the problem is the interface. The `$obj->{_components}` deals with very low level details and the `$self->components` is a level above that. I don't particularly like mixing levels of abstraction like that.

The original code has `components` doing the job of setting and getting depending on the size of the argument list. Through autovivification, it will initialize `$obj->{_components}` automatically, so you don't need the `$obj->{_components} = []` line except to set up the first call:

```
sub components {
    my $obj = shift;
    @_ ? push (@{$obj->{_components}}, @_) : @{$obj->{_components}};
}
```

But, I'd initialize it in `components` for the case where you call without arguments before you set any components:

```
sub components {
    my $obj = shift;
    $obj->{_components} = [] unless $obj->{_components};
    @_ ? push (@{$obj->{_components}}, @_) : @{$obj->{_components}};
}
```

With the [postfix deref](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) that's even simpler:

```
use v5.26;
sub components {
    my $obj = shift;
    $obj->{_components} = [] unless $obj->{_components};
    @_ ? push ( $obj->{_components}->@* , @_) : $obj->{_components}->@*;
}
```

But I'd change that up. A `push` returns a number, which probably isn't the interface you want. Get rid of the conditional operator and always return the full list at the end:

```
use v5.26;
sub components {
    my $obj = shift;
    $obj->{_components} = [] unless $obj->{_components};
    push $obj->{_components}->@* , @_ if @_;
    $obj->{_components}->@*;
}
```

And, back to your original query: that key is just a string the programmer chose. Often the `_` shows up before a key to show that it's metadata or something else that will be ingored. I don't know the intent here though. Instead of typing it out several times, define it once:

```
use v5.26;
sub components {
    state $key = '_components';
    my $obj = shift;
    $obj->{$key} = [] unless $obj->{$key};
    push $obj->{$key}->@* , @_ if @_;
    $obj->{$key}->@*;
}
```

Using the [experimental signatures feature](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/04/use-v5-20-subroutine-signatures/) cleans it up a bit more:

```
use v5.26;
use experimental qw(signatures);
sub components ($self, @args) {
    state $key = '_components';
    $obj->{$key} = [] unless $obj->{$key};
    push $obj->{$key}->@* , @args if @arg;
    $obj->{$key}->@*;
}
```

Comment: really appreciate this https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy